# Multiple game frames in construct 2 for new levels?

Tags: html, platform, construct-2

Hi there I'm new to Construct and have tried out a few platformer tutorials. I'm getting to grips with setting variables and collisions, I'm now at the stage where I want to start adding new levels. What the best way to effectively go to a new level, I know in flash this would be a new frame on the timeline, what would you do in construct 2?

Comment: Might be a better fit for http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks for the response, hadn't heard of gamedev.

Answer (score 3):

In Construct 2, Layouts are the term for levels/scenes/frames.  You can add and remove layouts in the Project Bar.